# Is there an infinite field such that every non-zero element has finite multiplicative order?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Is there an infinite field such that every non-zero element has finite multiplicative order?

I did not find any example of such a field, but also did not see anything that forbids the existence of one. Any help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}_p$ does the job for $p$ a prime number.

Take $x\in\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}$ such that $x\neq 0$ then $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$ is a finite field and hence $x$ is of $\underline{\text{multiplicative}}$ finite order in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$ and hence in  $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}$.

Of course, the last thing to know is that every algebraic closure is infinite which can be googled...

Comment: So where is the problem? An element $x$ of the algebraic closure of $\mathbb F_p$ is contained in some $F_{p^n}$, hence fulfills $x^{p^n-1}=1$

Comment: @Arthur, I precised my answer, every element of the algebraic closure is contained in a finite field.

Comment: BTW, every infinite subfield of $\overline{\mathbb F_p}$  (see the answer of @Circonflexe) is also an example. This way one gets **all** fields having the required property: every infinite algebraic extension of $\mathbb{F}_p$ for some prime $p$ has the required property and conversely, every field with the required property must be an infinite algebraic extension of a finite field $\mathbb{F}_p$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Look at the union of all fields $\mathbb F_{p^{\ell^n}}$, where $p$ and $\ell$ are two fixed prime numbers. This is an infinite field, and all elements are roots of unity.

Comment: I haven't heard the term 'reunion' before, does it have any mathematical synonyms?

Comment: The term is unusual, but the user obviously meant the union of the chain $\mathbb{F}_{p^l}\subseteq \mathbb{F}_{p^{^{l^2}}}\subseteq \mathbb{F}_{p^{^{l^3}}}\cdots$

Comment: Yes. Non-native English speaker here, sorry.

Comment: The term "ascending union" is common in English.